# Bulk insert with SQL Server where one column has many values and all other columns take on preset values

Tags: sql-server

I have a table (`Table1`) that has 4 columns (`ID1, ID2, Percent, Time, Expired`).  I want to insert a bunch of new rows in that table where `ID1` is taken from another SQL query I have and all the other columns are set to some specified values.

So I have my query:

```
SELECT someID FROM other_tables WITH other_conditions
```

And essentially what I want to do is

```
FOR v in <above query>
     Insert New row into Table1 (v, some second id, some percent, some time, some expired value)
```

**EDIT** I'm not opposed to not doing this in a loop, just don't know what the best way to insert the data is

Comment: So change your `SELECT` to include those values. What's your question?

Comment: does `(SELECT colName FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON <stuff> WHERE <other_stuff>)` return multiple values

Comment: @JeroenMostert the values in the first query are not currently in the table.  I want to add those into the table with the other columns as specified

Comment: @scsimon yes it does

Comment: Are you just looking for `INSERT Table1(x,y,z) SELECT someID, some y, some z FROM ...`? `some y` and `some z` can be constants or derived from other columns as you please.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you're getting at -- do you want to generate multiple output rows based on a single input row? That can be done with `CROSS APPLY`. (Do not, for all that's holy, use cursors.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert yes that's exactly what I'm trying to do, and I'm not against or for cursors.  There is an answer posted that uses them.  Could you provide an alternate?

Comment: Better with cross apply, i just assume you thought of loop since you use a lot of python it seems. Cursors should be used as a last resort since they can be resource intensive, but they are there for a reason and when used properly are fine.

Comment: @scsimon I do use a lot of python, I'm googling cross apply now but would welcome any suggestions to use that as a means to solve this problem

Comment: @sedavidw i just put a cross apply edit in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a cursor and fetch I think for what you are trying to accomplish. Here is a shell for you...

**WITH CURSOR**

```
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR
SELECT DISTINCT colName FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON <stuff> WHERE <other_stuff>

DECLARE @ID VARCHAR(4) --or what ever is needed

OPEN c
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @ID


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Table1 (ID, ID2, Percent, Time, Expired)
        VALUES (@ID, some second id, some percent, some time, some expired value)
        WHERE ID = @ID

        FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @ID
    END

CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c
```

**WITH CROSS APPLY (DUMMY DATA)**

```
if object_id('tempdb..#ids') is not null drop table #ids
if object_id('tempdb..#idDetails') is not null drop table #idDetails

create table #ids (id int)
insert into #ids (id) values
(1),(2),(3)


select i.*, d.*
into #idDetails
from #ids i cross apply (select 2 as id2 ,2.0 as per,'1/1/2016' as dt,'x' as x) d

select * from #idDetails
```

**WITH CROSS APPLY (EXAMPLE WITH YOUR TABLES)**

```
select i.someID, d.*
into #idDetails
from other_tables i 
cross apply (select 'some second id' as id2 ,'some percent' as [Percent],'1/1/2016 14:55:22' as [SomeTime] as dt,'SomeExpiredVal' as [ExpiredVal]) d

select * from #idDetails
```

Comment: I'm confused about the section with "YOUR SPECIFIC CODE".  It says `select i.someID, d.*` is that from the original query.  I'm confused as to where that original query is populating input here

Comment: I was showing you what it should look like when you select from your table without using temporary tables as I did in the example above.  You used someID in your post so I used it too

Comment: You will need to replace the values in the cross apply with whatever you want to use

Comment: Yes I did, sorry had to run out yesterday.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @sedavidw  no worries at all. Just wanted to make sure you were set!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something, but you need a table valued function which returns the desired row for each row in Table1

```
create function fn_get_new_recs(id int) 
RETURNS @results TABLE (Id INT,<other columns you need>)
AS
BEGIN
--Query here to return new records for a single id

END
```

then use CROSS APPLY

```
INSERT INTO Table1(Id,Col1,Col2,Col3)
SELECT ST.Id,ST.Col1,ST.Col2,ST.Col3
FROM Table1 T
cross apply fn_get_new_recs(T.Id) ST
```